Read ini key longer than 255 characters
I would like to read the key from the ini file and load it into the listbox.
Everything works until the ini key exceeds 255 characters, then it gives an error
ini look like here:
[Islands]
name=Island1-6,Island2-6,Island3-6,Island4-6,stash-1,Island5-6,Island6-6,Island7-6,Island8-6,stash-1,Island9-6,Island10-6,Islandname11-6,Islandname12-6,stash-1,Islandname13-6,Islandname14-6,Islandname15-6,Islandname16-6,234234-1,2334-2,234324-3,234324-5,123123-3,end

int v = 0;
string t1Stone = new IniFile(iniFilePath).Read("name", "Islands");
Console.WriteLine(t1Stone);
string[] t1StoneValues = t1Stone.Split(',');
Loop:;
string t10 = t1StoneValues[v];

if (t10 == "end")
{
    goto Start;
}
else
{
    if (t10 == "")
    {
        goto Start;
    }
    else
    {
        listBoxWyspy.Items.Add(t10);
        v++;
        if (v < 1000)
        {
            goto Loop;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

}
Start:;


That's not the key, that's the value. The key is name.

"it gives an error" is not very descriptive. what error do you get, specifically? Also, there's no built-in IniFile class in .NET, so please identify where you've got that from.

And here is a link to the classic 1968 article by Dijkstra: Goto statement considered harmful. A while loop would be much clearer.

error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

As long as v is less than 1000 you look at the next item, but there aren't a 1000 items in the list. You should look at t1stoneValues-1 instead.

and what I mean is whether it is possible to read this key value sequentially after the decimal point or another option. the error appears when the key value exceeds 255 characters

string t1Stone = new IniFile(iniFilePath).Read("name", "Islands");
Islandname1-6,Islandname2-6,Islandname3-6,Islandname4-6,stash-1,Islandname5-6,Islandname6-6,Islandname7-6,Islandname8-6,stash-1,Islandname9-6,Islandname10-6,Islandname11-6,Islandname12-6,stash-1,Islandname13-6,Islandname14-6,Islandname15-6,stash-1,123131
this is what it looks like after loading. it only saves 255 characters and cuts off the rest

Why are you hand-coding a .ini reader? Just leverage Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini instead.

Goto should be avoided. Do this instead:
int v = 0;
string t1Stone = new IniFile(iniFilePath).Read("name", "Islands");
Console.WriteLine(t1Stone);
string[] t1StoneValues = t1Stone.Split(',');
foreach (string s in t1StoneValues)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && listBoxWyspy.Items.Count < 1000 && !s.Equals("end"))
    {
       listBoxWyspy.Items.Add(s);
    }
}

This way you only work on the strings that are there.
EDIT
I would avoid using ini-files in this day and age, but if I had to I would organize the file thus:
[Islands]
islandcount = 24
name1=Island1-6
name2=Island2-6
name3=Island3-6
name4=Island4-6
name5=stash-1
name6=Island5-6
name7=Island6-6
name8=Island7-6
name9=Island8-6
name10=stash-1
name11=Island9-6
name12=Island10-6
name13=Islandname11-6,
name14=Islandname12-6
name15=stash-1
name16=Islandname13-6
name17=Islandname14-6
name18=Islandname15-6
name19=Islandname16-6
name20=234234-1
name21=2334-2
name22=234324-3
name23=234324-5,
name24=123123-3

Then I would read it like this:
var myIni = new IniFile(iniFilePath);
int count = int.Parse(myIni.Read("islandcount", "Islands"));
for (int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
    string s = myIni.Read($"name{i}", "Islands")
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && listBoxWyspy.Items.Count < 1000)
    {
       listBoxWyspy.Items.Add(s);
    }
}

If you look at driver ini-files that's normally how it's done.

now it works, it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't fully load the key value. then I have to look for another way. Is it possible to read only the sections from the ini file and make a list of them in the listbox? that would solve all my problems

ini file that looks like this:
[island1]
lvl=1
[island2]
lvl=1
[island3]
lvl=2
and now the point is for it to read only the section names and make a list out of it in the listbox

it works perfectly. Thank you. now I have textbox for island name and combobox for select lvl buttons add and remove and listbox like up. and now I need it to add the island name and level to the list and save it in the ini file after press ADD and remove from list after selected and press Remove. I'm sorry but I'm still learning

this its my old:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String nazwaWyspy = textBoxIslandName.Text;
String levelWyspy = comboBoxLevel.Text;
listBoxWyspy.Items.Add(nazwaWyspy);
textBoxIslandName.Text = "";
comboBoxLevel.Text = "";
string TimeslotItems = "";
foreach (string s in listBoxWyspy.Items)
{
string name = s;
TimeslotItems += (name) + ",";
Console.WriteLine(TimeslotItems);
var MyIni2 = new IniFile(iniFilePath);
MyIni2.Write("name", "Islands");
}
}

the part about adding to the list works, the part about saving to the ini file does not work. I want it to be saved under the appropriate number
